# Managed Package that contains Shared Activities features fails to install

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I developed a managed package that is supposed to work on orgs with or without shared activities enabled. That's why I'm first figuring out whether this feature is enabled in the org:

```
Boolean isSharedActivitiesEnabled = true; 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.EventRelation.fields.getMap(); 
if (M.containsKey('IsParent')) { 
    System.debug('============== shared activities are enabled.'); 
} else { 
    isSharedActivitiesEnabled = false; 
    System.debug('============== shared activities are NOT enabled.'); 
}
```

Then I'm populating fields that are available according to

```
EventRelation newEventRelation = new EventRelation( 
    EventId = newEventId, 
    RelationId = contact.Id 
); 
if (isSharedActivitiesEnabled) { 
    newEventRelation.IsWhat = false; 
    newEventRelation.IsParent = true; 
    newEventRelation.IsInvitee = false; 
} else { 
    newEventRelation.Status = attendeeStatus; 
}
```

In an earlier version I did not populate the fields IsWhat and IsParent and IsInvitee and the managed package could be installed in any org. But since I am populating the fields IsWhat and IsParent and IsInvitee, this managed package can only be installed in orgs where shared activities are enabled.

So how can I develop code that works in both types of orgs?
Thanks a lot
Alex

Comment: If I code logic to use sharedactivities only, then while installing managed package will I get error if sharedactivities is not enabled in client org (org where package is being installed)? ie do I need to force every customer to enable same first and then able to install managed package? please advise!

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is: dynamic Apex:

```
if (isSharedActivitiesEnabled) {
  newEventRelation.put('IsWhat', false);
  newEventRelation.put('IsParent', true);
  newEventRelation.put('IsInvitee', false);
} else {
  newEventRelation.put('Status', attendeeStatus);
}
```

does the trick.